# Expo App not retrieving localhost API data on Android Emulator, works in emulator's browser

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo, localhost

I am using Expo to create a React Native Application. I am consuming a localhost API run with .Net.

The web version runs fine but when I try and consume the API with my app on an android emulator I get the following error:

```
Network request failed
at node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:123:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:379:16 in callTimers
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I am using `https://10.0.2.2:7203/api/payments` and I have tried both the HTTPS and HTTP versions. I can get the response in the emulator's browser after agreeing to the warning that the connection is not secure. I suspect that it has something to do with the SSL certificate but I cannot figure out how to make it work in the application.

Here is the fetch request:

```
        const fetchData = fetch(this.props.api)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => this.setState({ items: result }))
            .catch(reason => console.log(reason));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing your backend through emulator's browser first. It could be easier to troubleshoot any issues.

Also try synchronizing your emulator's time to be the same as your host machine time. Time mismatch could cause SSL issues.